# how to use boto to get aws sqs message already in flight

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I tried `boto api` and seems that no api can get message number already in flight? Does anyone give me a hint how to get this number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the messages in flight or any of the other attributes of an SQS queue in boto, you need to do this:

```
import boto.sqs
c = boto.sqs.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
queue = c.lookup('myqueue')
attr = queue.get_attributes()
```

This will a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
{u'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': u'0',
 u'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed': u'0',
 u'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible': u'0',
 u'CreatedTimestamp': u'1412270007',
 u'DelaySeconds': u'0',
 u'LastModifiedTimestamp': u'1412270007',
 u'MaximumMessageSize': u'262144',
 u'MessageRetentionPeriod': u'345600',
 u'QueueArn': u'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:723405645490:16ac1da3-564c-43aa-8dcb-4db41ece50ea',
 u'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': u'0',
 u'VisibilityTimeout': u'30'}
```

I believe the `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible` is equivalent to the in-flight statistic reported by the console.

Comment: I tried your script and works. Thansk

Comment: for newer versions of boto you might need to change to this  `sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
        sqs_queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='yourqueue')
        messages = sqs_queue.attributes["ApproximateNumberOfMessages"]`